# CIMC Power Delay Type Random Power On

Tags: cisco

I'm configuring the power policy for a new Cisco C240 with the latest firmware version.  One of the options is Power Delay Type.  The choices are fixed or random.  With fixed selected, you can customize the delay in seconds.  That makes sense to me.

What I can't figure out is what the option random is for.  Does anyone know what the random option is for an why you would want to use it?

The configuration guides I've looked at aren't much help.  They just show that you can configure both options.

[image]

Comment: normally these odd options are from customer requests. The only thing I can think of is maybe for offset a mass poweron/reboot. So the power systems don't get overloaded or set off datacenter alarms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on a related case with Cisco I asked about the Random option.  As SpiderIce guessed, the option is to randomize server boots in the range of 0-240 seconds.